# Can't add Button to JPanel if the button is initialized in another class

Tags: java, swing

So I've got my Surface class, which extends from JPanel. Then I've got my Snake class, which extends from Surface.
So, my problem is, I can't add Buttons to my Surface, if I initialize the Button in my Snake class. To make it more understandable:

This works in my Surface constructor:

```
JButton testButton = new JButton("");
add(testButton);
testButton.setBounds(100,100,10,10);
```

This **doesnt** work in my Snake class:

```
JButton testButton = new JButton("");
super.add(testButton);
testButton.setBounds(100,100,10,10);
```

Not sure if its important. But this is my main function, where I also create my JFrame and initialize my Surface and my Snake

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // Create the JFrame
    JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
    jframe.setSize(800, 400);
    jframe.setResizable(false);
    jframe.setLayout(null);
    jframe.setVisible(true);

    Surface mySurface = new Surface();

    jframe.add(mySurface); // Add the JPanel to the JFrame

    new Snake(true);
}
```

And my Surface:

```
public Surface()
{
    // Create the JPanel
    setLayout(null);
    setBounds(0, 0, 400, 400);
    setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

    // Add the KeyListener
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(true);
    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocusInWindow();
}
```

So where is my mistake? How can I add a button to my JPanel from my Snake class?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should place Snake into UI. Currently you only create instance of it and do not display anywhere. Try this:

```
// Create the JFrame
JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
jframe.setSize(800, 400);
jframe.setResizable(false);
jframe.setLayout(null);
jframe.setVisible(true);

Surface mySurface = new Snake(true); //I do not know why you need boolean here, really

jframe.add(mySurface); // Add the JPanel to the JFrame
```

Comment: It worked just perfect on the first try. Thank you very much :)